# Naming strategy for a java boolean read method

Tags: java, json, jackson

What is the correct get method convention for a boolean variable in a Java class. For example:

```
private boolean qExist;

public boolean isqExist() {
    return qExist;
}
public void setqExist(boolean qExist) {
    this.qExist = qExist;
}
```

the above methods are generated by eclipse. Whereas the wsimport generates 'qExist' in a .xsd file as

```
public boolean isQExist() {
    return qExist;
}
public void setQExist(boolean qExist) {
    this.qExist = qExist;
}
```

Jackson JSON serializer expects the first method to be present in a class otherwise it appends the variable's value (in this case 'qexist' - all lowercase) to the JSON object. when it passed to web ui, javascript does not know the variable since it is expecting 'qExist'.

This may be a bug in Jackson because if the boolean variable startswith two or more lowercase letters then Jackson goes with the second method above.

I did solve the problem by telling the Jackson object mapper to not to look for setters/getters/is methods for values but look at fields.

Comment: Capitalizing the "Q" is the usual way. Eclipse is not that bright.

Comment: isQExist and setQExist is the standard naming convention followed in most of the strict typed languages

Comment: As a note on English...`doesQExist` is universally accepted as being more grammatical (and more *natural*) than `isQExist`. I prefer to maximize readability rather than overly conforming to the less useful aspects of the java bean spec. Jackson can be instructed to refer to the field directly, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would capitalize every new word - no matter how many letters it has

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity what does the Q represent? The term "correct" may depend on how you are using the getter/setting in reflection. I would use:

```
public boolean isQExist() {
    return qExist;
}
public void setQExist(boolean qExist) {
    this.qExist = qExist;
}
```

Comment: Actually the getter and setter methods are generated by wsimport thru maven plugin. I think adding Json annotations is not good practice on generated code. thanks for the inputs. I just want to point out  that jackson library failing when it has single lowercase letter vs multiple while serializing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want to have to use the field directly, you could just remove the tight coupling to the POJO structure and use annotations.

```
public static final String BLAH_PROPERTY = "qExists";

private boolean blah;

@JsonProperty(BLAH_PROPERTY)
public boolean isBlah() {
    return blah;
}

@JsonProperty(BLAH_PROPERTY)
public void setBlah(boolean blah) {
    this.blah = blah;
}
```